# Genemu autocomplete won't work

Tags: forms, symfony, autocomplete

I'm trying to use genemu autocomplete to display a list of entities. I followed every step, but for some reason, it doesn't work : all I got is a text input, and nothing shows up when I type something inside.

So far, my build looks like this :

```
        ->add('departure', 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity', array(
'class' => 'AOFVH\FlyBundle\Entity\City',
'property' => 'name',                          
))
```

Twig template looks like this :

```
 <form id="msform" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" {{ form_enctype(search) }}>
            <!-- progressbar -->
                <div class="form-group">
                {{form_widget(search.departure)}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                {{form_widget(search.arrival)}}
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                {{form_widget(search.passengers)}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                {{form_widget(search.precisedate)}}
                </div>
                <hr>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default hp3">CHERCHER</button>
            </form>
```

And I included jquery and jquery-ui. What did I miss ?

Comment: try `<form method="GET"` inspect the network tab if any request is done and whats the error code, check console for errors anyway

Comment: and have a look at the generated html, maybe theres some invalid stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these bundles comes with javascript and css of their own. Did you included them? I believe that you use **GenemuFormBundle**? If that is correct, there is paragraph for that as well:

> You use GenemuFormBundle and you seen that it does not work! Maybe you have forgotten form_javascript or form_stylesheet.
>
> The principle is to separate the javascript, stylesheet and html. This allows better integration of web pages.

Take a look at their example page: [Docs.](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/template.md)

Comment: Oh god. A single typo. form_jaascript. Thank you so much !

Comment: Yes, it happens sometimes. :) Glad to be of help.